# HIVE table - Get records which are closest to a given numeric value

Tags: sql, hiveql

From a hive table, I want records which are closest to a given value of each of the columns. 
E.g.
The table has columns - total_score, avg_score, etc. I want to get records which have total_score and avg_score close or equal to "a given value".

**Note - Table has approx. 183 million rows and I want 1,50,000 records which are closest/equal to the given value of each of the columns.**

Please help me with the process of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general concept needs to be top x, ordered by the absolute value of difference between parameter value and values in list.